# Conditional Child Routing (Angular)

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, parent-child

Is it possible to have a conditionally display to a child route as a default?

I'm trying to have users land on a particular child route, depending on what they ordered in the past (i.e., land on the channel page for a store, online or social).

If they ordered from Store, they go to the store child route.
If they did not order from Store, then they go to Online child route.
If they did not order from Store/Child, they go to Social.

The user will have had to order from >1 channel.

The below works, but if I click from some page to Channel, then click Back on the browser, the Channel page shows as empty (i.e., it seems the app defaults to an empty page for router-outlet.

Below is my router module

```
   {
      path: 'Channel/:id',
      component: ChannelComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'Store', component: StoreComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'Online', component: OnlineComponent
        },
        {
          path: 'Social', component: SocialComponent
        }
      ]
    }
```

Below is from my channel.component.ts

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.orderedFromChannel= this.getTypes(this.userId); 
      if (this.orderedFromChannel['Store']) {
        this.showStore();
      } else if (this.orderedFromChannel['Online']) {
        this.showOnline();
      } else if (this.orderedFromChannel['Social']) {
        this.showSocial();
      } 
    }

      showStore() {
        this.router.navigate(["Store"], {relativeTo: this.route})
      }
      showOnline() {
        this.router.navigate(["Online"], {relativeTo: this.route})
      }
      showSocial() {
        this.router.navigate(["Social"], {relativeTo: this.route})
      }
```

Below is from my channel.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: This is probably because you're going back to another ChannelComponent route and it doesn't re-init. It's already loaded. You will have to watch router events or param changes inside the Channel Component.

Answer (score 0):

To set a default route you can set an empty path "" at the bottom of your children array. So if neither of the children's route match, it will go to the last path. Something like this:

```
{
  path: 'Channel/:id',
  component: ChannelComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'Store', component: StoreComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'Online', component: OnlineComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'Social', component: SocialComponent
    },
    {
      path: '', component: StoreComponent //if you want store to be default
    },
  ]
}
```

Or, you can use a redirect:

```
{
  path: 'Channel/:id',
  component: ChannelComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'Store', component: StoreComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'Online', component: OnlineComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'Social', component: SocialComponent
    },
    {
      path: '', redirectTo: 'Store' //if you want store to be default
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks...but this seems to just always loads the store component.  I only want to send to the Store component based on a condition (i.e., if appears in this.orderedFromChannel['Store'])

Comment: you can check out [PlatformLocation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PlatformLocation-class.html) to handle the back button in your child components